# loop through multiple objects inside the first array from JSON data displaying two arrays with objects in React using FUNCTION COMPONENT

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, data-structures, ecmascript-6

what is the best and simple way to access this data in ReactJS using ***FUNCTION COMPONENT***?

The problem is that I have two arrays with objects and I want **TO LOOP THROUGH THE FIRST ARRAY AND DISPLAY EACH ITEMS FROM THE OBJECT INSIDE.**

## console.log(data)

```
(20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
(20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

**This is how the data are represented in each array**

```
0:
  first_name: "Jane"
  id: 6
  last_name: "Doe"
  city: "budapest"
1:
  first_name: "Michael"
  id: 10
  last_name: "Holland"
  city: "France"

etc...
```

**(Please take a look at the picture below to understand what I mean by "0:" or "1:". That is the way the json data is displayed inside the array by records i guess)**

[image]

My current solution below only work when you have **one array** with 
objects inside but in this case as you can see I have two.

```
const items = [
    {first_name: "Jane",id: "6",last_name: "Doe",city: "Budapest"},
    {first_name: "David",id: "10",last_name: "Smith",city: "Paris"},
  ]

  const newData = items.map((item) => {
    return (
      <div className="something" key={item.id}>{item.first_name}</div>
    )
  })
```

Please note that I am using ***ReactJS 16.9***

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `0:` is json key name or array's first value? , please provide how your whole data object looks

Comment: @VivekDoshi I have updated the post above with a picture to answer your question. That is the way the json data is displayed inside each array by records i guess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am getting you correctly, then you can merge both Array and then use it.

Something like this :

```
// First Array
const stations = [
    {first_name: "Jane",id: "6",last_name: "Doe",city: "Budapest"},
    {first_name: "David",id: "10",last_name: "Smith",city: "Paris"},
];

// Second Array
const stations2 = [
    {first_name: "Jane",id: "6",last_name: "Doe",city: "Budapest"},
    {first_name: "David",id: "10",last_name: "Smith",city: "Paris"},
];

const allStations = [...stations , ...stations2 ]; // <----- HERE

const newData = allStations.map((item) => {
    return (
        <div className="something" key={item.id}>{item.first_name}</div>
    )
})
```

Comment: Yes. your solution is correct but my current problem is that the variable `data` contains the two arrays thats why when i `console.log(data)` it show the two arrays. How can I achieve the same result with one variable named `data` that holds the value of both `stations` and `stations2` based on your answer. (this is why i showed the json they are both coming from the same variable `data`)

Comment: in that case data must be json , json must have key, I can't see that , so your console.log is being fired twice, means you are getting 2 array but not at the same time, but one after another, I can help you more if you can create small demo on https://stackblitz.com/ with your query

Comment: Thank your for your help. it is actually being fired twice, thats why i thought i had two arrays.